# Swift - Binary operator cannot be applied to operands of type

Tags: ios, swift, progress-bar

I am trying to set up a progress bar on a timer and have this code to try and implement it however I get a series of errors in the function which is declared outside of the viewDidLoad. Here is what I am working with:

```
import UIKit

class LoadingScreen: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
 var time : Float = 0.0
        var timer: NSTimer

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector:Selector("setProgress"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)



    } //close viewDidLoad


func setProgress() {
        time += 0.1
        progressView.progress = time / 3
        if time >= 3 {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }



} //close class
```

Here is a screenshot of all the errors I get:
[image]

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare your variables outside viewDidLoad

```
@IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!
var time : Float = 0.0
var timer: NSTimer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
.......
```

The binary operand error is the result of you trying to perform an operation on two different types. `time` is actually a function declared in `time.h` which returns a `typealias time_t`. This is why it may look like you're referencing your own variable. Really you're trying to add 0.1 (a double) to a `time` pointer.

Comment: Bonus points if you explain the strange error message :) Why `operands of type '(UnsafeMutablePointer<time_t>) -> time_t' ...` ?

Comment: You might want to elaborate on: "time is actually a type", that does not make sense.

Comment: Makes me wonder why the compiler would decided that time.h was involved in that method but I suspect that the question is missing code.

Comment: @zaph: Almost all BSD library functions are imported into Swift via the Darwin module. `time_t time(time_t *tloc);` is imported as `func time(_: UnsafeMutablePointer<time_t>) -> time_t`. Since functions are value types in Swift, a bare `time` is a value of the type `func time(_: UnsafeMutablePointer<time_t>) -> time_t`. So this is quite correct now (+1).

Comment: @Max Thank you for your answer. It has definitely helped but now, after putting the variables outside the viewDidLoad, I get an error saying the Class has no initializers.

Comment: Use `var timer: NSTimer?` put a question mark after NSTimer to declare it as a conditional. Remember to unwrap it when you use timer with `if let` or `timer!` if you know it is not nil.

Comment: I thought that made it an optional buy anyway I got it working by adding the ? so thanks for that. For anyone else interested, I then used `timer!` now, just got to try and find a way to make it add progress more often, to make it look smoother...

Comment: Oops meant optional, can't edit now. Anyway to make it smoother just use `- setProgress:animated:` method of UIProgressView rather than `progressView.progress`